# extract ArrayList values passed in constructor and use this values in other method

Tags: java

i used a constructor parameter to pass an ArrayList but i have something wrong with my paint method. I would really appreciate if anyone could explain (simply) why my Coordinates seems like null. I try to give a simple example so i can get a better understanding).

```
public class Main {  
   private static ArrayList<Integer> xCoords = new ArrayList<Integer>();
   private static ArrayList<Integer> yCoords = new ArrayList<Integer>();

 public static void main(String[] args) {
...
...
    for (int i = 0; i < best.tourSize(); i++) {
        xCoords.add(i, best.getAdress(i).x);
        yCoords.add(i, best.getAdress(i).y);
     }

new Draw(xCoords, yCoords);
 }
```

> second class

```
    public class Draw extends JPanel {

    private  ArrayList<Integer> xCoord= new ArrayList<Integer>();
    private  ArrayList<Integer> yCoord = new ArrayList<Integer>();

 public void paint(Graphics g){        

     // the issue is here, xCoord.size() is null. how can i do to recover coordinate passed in construct from main class and use it in this method
          for(int i = 1; i <this.xCoord.size() ; i++){      
          ...
            g.drawLine(xCoord.get(i-1)+offset, yCoord.get(i-1)+ offset, xCoord.get(i)+ offset, yCoord.get(i)+ offset);
           }
       }

// construct

   public Draw(ArrayList<Integer> xCoord, ArrayList<Integer> yCoord) {         
     ...
    f.setVisible(true);                   
    }
```

> as you can see when i instanciate the Draw class, the construct is called but i want to use the method Paint to generate a graph using x, y coordinates passed form main method !

Comment: Post your draw constructor code completely

Comment: **i Need to use Paint method in constructor to be initialised**      `public Draw(ArrayList<Integer> xCoord, ArrayList<Integer> yCoord) {
                   
  final int width = 400; // Breite des Fensters
  final int height = 450; // Hoehe des Fensters
  JFrame f = new JFrame();
  f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
  f.setSize(width, height);
  f.add(this);
  f.setVisible(true);                    
                }`

Comment: 1. You haven't copied List values passed to your Draw method

Comment: 2. I think your design is wrong. You could create your view in draw constructor itself. But if you want to continue with your current design go ahead and call `repaint()` draw object

Comment: i.e `Draw draw= new Draw(xCoords, yCoords);` and then `draw.repaint()`, if it not affect also call 'draw.revalidate()'

Comment: Thank you **Pragnani** for your Suggestion, i try really to create this view in my contruct without creating a new class Paint but i did not find the logic

Answer (score 0):

in your constructor of Draw class do below changes.

//assign the fields declared in Draw classes
//from the ones created in Main class

this.xCord = xCord;

this.yCord = yCord;

plus when you do this   you need not do initialize your ArrayList objects using 'new' in Draw class, as you are creating and adding values in the Main class and in Draw class you just need to use the same lists.

Comment: Thanks **nits** i forgot to assign the variable of my class on which my method is invoked :) it works pretty !